# Retrieve guest user company name from Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, power-automate, dynamics-crm-portals

I have power platform portal, and i'am using Azure AD for registering.

Only Guest users in Azure AD may register on the portal.

I have two problems/questions:

When I create a guest user on Azure AD, I fill in his company name. But when  this guest registers on portal, his company name isn't mentionned on his portal profile.

So, for the workaround,  I created an automated flow to get the user data from Azure AD, But the connector did not return the company name. In other words,  the company name is not on the returned attributes list.

Ideas?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The Power Apps Per app plan and user plan can retrieve Company name as Premium connectors (A connector may provide tables of data or actions) are added. If its Include only with Office, it cannot retrieve.

You must assign your guest the same license that's required for non-guests to run the app. For instance, if the app uses premium connectors, a Power Apps per app plan or a Power Apps per user plan must be assigned to the guest.

[image]

Reference Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/share-app-guests
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/connections-list